# Android Gallery Thumbnail Images

Tags: android, image, thumbnails, android-gallery, image-compression

I am developing an application which loads images from local device storage.
I used compression technique code:

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fo);
fo.flush();
fo.close();
```

where picture is a bitmap.
This shows a low quality unreadable image.

Is there any efficient compression technique. 
Also, how does android gallery show thumbnail images which are readable and of smaller file size?

Comment: Have you tried changing `90` by increasing one by one ?

Comment: I also did 100. Then also I got a blurred image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using ThumbnailUtils:

```
   Bitmap picture = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path_to_your_file), FINAL_WIDTH, FINAL_HEIGHT);
```

Image size is reduced much

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help you

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageUri) // will come from gallery
            .resize(imageWidth, imageWidth).centerInside()
            .into(imageview);
```

I have done this

```
    public static final int GRID_PADDING = 8; // in dp
    public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS  = 3; 
    Resources r = getResources();
        float padding =   TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,GRID_PADDING,r.getDisplayMetrics());
imageWidth = (int) ((getScreenWidth()) - ((NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) /   NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
```

Comment: @Bhaskar Gurram you need to do some changes according to your need, for me its working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found another hack which looks more efficient. Wrote it below http://stackoverflow.com/a/37463734/4158663

Comment: I will try this new method also @nisarg

Comment: Okay no problem, I'll also try